# Pattern matching with regexes in Scala

Tags: regex, scala, pattern-matching

Why doesn't this work?

```
val isGovt = """Govt .*""".r
val Govt = "Govt 23 foobar"
Govt match {
    case isGovt(_) => println("match works")
    case _ => print("nope. doesn't work")
}
```

It prints 'nope. doesn't work'.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
val isGovt = """Govt .*""".r
```

to

```
val isGovt = """(Govt .*)""".r
```

When you use a regex as an extractor, the bound variables correspond to the regex's groups. Your regex had none.

You could also simply keep your regex as is and do:

```
case isGovt() =>
```

This is probably more like hat you had in mind.

Comment: +1 Or change `case isGovt(_) => println("match works")` to `case isGovt => println("match works")`

Comment: You meant `case isGovt()` I guess. Added to my answer, thanks.

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles What if I want to match something like this: """(Govt \\d.*)""".r ? This does not seem to work for say "Govt 23 foobar"

Comment: Your regex is wrong: you doubled the backslash but you should not because you are already using triple-quotes, which don't require escaping. Try `"""(Govt \d.*)""".r `